# When YOU say 'you', instead of 'I' - what is that?

Tags: terminology

What is the name of the mechanism when YOU say 'you', instead of 'I' when **YOU'RE talking about yourself**, *but with someone else?*

The capitalised instances above serve as an example of what I'm talking about :)

Comment: is this related to the third person point of view?

Comment: I don't know, that's my question :)

Comment: I don't think you're talking about yourself when you use this construction. You might want to edit to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: It's a less pretentious alternative to "you", cf. _when you are talking about yourself_ vs _when one is talking about oneself_. This use of "one" as a personal pronoun is only found in the 3rd person form.

Comment: Please try to phrase your question more clearly or it will be thrown out. You need to take the trouble to give specific examples. Are you asking about the following alternatives, for example, "I got up, dressed, had my breakfast, and jumped into the car." v. "You get up, get dressed, have your breakfast, jump into the car." or what?

Comment: @David, someone answered my question correctly, that's why I accepted the answer. Have you read it? Feel free to throw out the question though, if that'll make you happy.

Comment: In any circumstances it is not "being nice" to use the phrase "if that'll make you happy". In this case it is particularly inappropriate as I was (1) performing a list duty, (2) trying to help you. SE tries to produce Q & As which will be of use to many people. To maintain quality members with a certain "reputation" (= score) can vote for questions be closed, and in such case they are placed on a queue for others to review. All I saw was your question on the queue marked as unclear. I think it is, but rather than voting to close, and not noticing the date, I suggested how it might be improved.

Comment: I would add that no individual can throw a question out. For it to be put on hold it needs five people to vote to close. I can only add my vote (or not). In saying that it would be thrown out I was warning that it had already attracted two close votes and would likely attract more. Again, trying to be helpful.

Comment: @David, I think the best use of our time right now would be for you to vote to close it ;). Thanks for your help with the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just one of the definitions of "you":

**You** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/you)

> 2.Used to refer to any person in general
>
> *"after a while, you get used to it"*
> *"This leaflet tells you what general line you should take."*

**Generic you** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you)

> In English grammar and in particular in casual English, *generic you*, *impersonal you* or *indefinite you* is the pronoun *you* in its use in referring to an unspecified person, as opposed to its use as the second person pronoun.